# Compare mouse positions using pyautogui in Python

Tags: python, mouse

How can I be able to compare the `pyautogui.position()[0]` (which is the X coordinates) to the previous x position in order to determine if the mouse cursor was going left or right? Do I need to make use of multi-threading since the `pyautogui` method is called every time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Edit (added explanation):
You check the difference in x coordinates 0.1 seconds apart to judge the movement direction of the mouse pointer. To update the mouse pointer movement direction in parallell you can thread the function.

```
import _thread
import pyautogui
import time

def left_or_right():
    while True:
        x1 = pyautogui.position()[0]
        time.sleep(0.1)
        x2 = pyautogui.position()[0]
        diff = x2 - x1
        if diff > 0:
            print('going right')
        elif diff < 0:
            print('going left')
        else:
            print('not moving')

_thread.start_new_thread(left_or_right, ())
```

Comment: There should be some explanation as well.